# Unclear about why /dev/dri/renderD128 is missing

Tags: centos, drivers, nvidia, display, graphics

I'm trying to troubleshoot something for my infrastructure team around the use of EGL as a backend for the VirtualGL program. I believe my issues come from a missing `/dev/dri/renderD128` device file on centos 7, what is supposed to be done to create this `renderD128` file? All I see in the `/dev/dri` is `card0`.

The gpu we are using is Nvidia and the most current driver is installed for the Tesla P100. I see all of the typical GPU device files in `/dev/nvidia*` such as `nvidia-uvm` `nvidiactl` ... If more specifics are needed I can try to find them out from the rest of the team, such as what flags were passed when the Nvidia driver's `.run` file was executed.

I'm not 100% percent convinced there's a problem with the driver install because I read https://forums.unraid.net/topic/72829-hardware-transcoding-plex-transcoding-not-working-renderd128-missing/  that the BIOS settings are what needed amending before the `renderD128` showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it turned out to be I was running an older version of the linux kernel (5.4) that didn't fully support my CPU (Rocket Lake). Only after updating the linux kernel to a newer version (5.11) along with a reboot did `/dev/dri/renderD128` finally appear.

So I would recommend making sure you're on the latest linux kernel. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the information. I'm testing these things on a super computer which doesn't run very recent kernels, so that must have been the issue.

Comment: Had the same problem when trying to run OpenCL on an Intel Skylake iGPU (GEN9) under Centos7 which only has a 3.10 kernel, i.e. does not fully support Skylake.